# Restore boot parameters to default value

Tags: boot, performance, dmesg

It feels like my system is getting slower and slower. I am using Ubuntu and my machine is an HP ProBook 450 i7 4x2.0GHz, 8GB RAM and an ordinary HDD. Still it takes ~2 minutes to boot, which in my opinion is way too much.

I was thinking on reinstalling the OS from scratch, but that is way too tedious since I have a lot of custom C++ libraries which would take ages to set-up again. Also, I expected Linux not to lose performance in such a way so quickly (I have this laptop for a year now).

My question is, is there any way to restore the boot options to default? Or anything else I could do to clean-up whatever is clogging the performance? I know SSD would help here, so please don't give me such answers, since there is obviously something wrong with the software.

Here is my [dmesg log](http://pastebin.com/3xVSK5Ym) and [bootchart](https://i.imgur.com/RxQxbha.png?1) if that could help as well.

Comment: "optical HD"? Did you install your OS on a DVD or what?

Comment: No, I just meant to say a regular HDD (SATA).

Comment: Could you provide the output to `sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda` and `smartctrl --all /dev/sda` because compared to [my boot chart](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sD8yN.png) your system seems to be wasting a lot of time in `iowait` (Use http://paste.ubuntu.com) to provide the output.  **Attention close voters: Problem also happens in default kernel!**

Comment: I believe you meant **smartctl**. The results are: [hdparm](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14394179/) and [smartctl](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14394162/). Also, thank you for the edit.